# select2 with <section> </section> not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a problem with `select2`.
Can this work at all?

If I select the first element eg. `ID 1` I can not select the `ID 2` anymore. But I choose the 3rd element from it is possible to `select2` and 1 but not the other way around.

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    }
];

$(".tmp").select2({
  data: data
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<!-- doesn't work -->
<p>
doesn´t work
</p>
<section class="tmp"></section>
<p>work</p>
<!--  work -->
<select class="tmp"></select>
```

Comment: Why would you use a `<section>` tag for that?

Comment: I have a html code that I would like to manipulate with Google TAGS JS. The current code should not be changed. Do you know what i mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your first select doesn't work because of your tags.

Change

```
<section class="tmp"></section>
```

to

```
<select class="tmp"></select>
```

Both will work now

Comment: Thanks.
I know it works that way. But I want to do that with a <section> tag :-)